# transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio

My project run very good.

After i added google analytics, it did not allow 64k in `.dex` file and i have already set :

```
defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true
}
```

but then it have bellow error

> :MainEntry:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':MainEntry:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\temp2\android-git\MainEntry\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar] (Can't process class [com/vtcpay/a/a.class] (Unknown verification type [143] in stack map frame))

Comment: do you add the multiDex support library?

Comment: i tried to add com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0. but  the same issue

Comment: what is your JDK version?

Comment: try to use jdk-8u101

Comment: i make answer that my help you

Answer (score 1):

1. be sure enabled multidex output, as shown in the following code snippet:

   ```
      android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

   defaultConfig {
       ...
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 21
       ...

       // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
        ...
   }

   dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
   }
   ```
2. make sure you added in your manifest  the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element

...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

for more detailes you can see [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: i have already set name at <application> . what happen if i change to android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

Comment: Build wont pass cause I need to have android:name for MainApplication.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you everybody
I have already found solution for this issue. i should add this script bellow default config.

A multidex configuration requires significantly increased build processing time because the build system must make complex decisions about what classes must be included in the primary DEX file and what classes can be included in secondary DEX files. This means that routine builds performed as part of the development process with multidex typically take longer and can potentially slow your development process.

```
productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
```