# Android :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug Duplicate zip entry

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get multiple warnings when rebuilding project in Android Studio 3 (I think warnings appeared when I switched to Android studio 3 from 2.3)

Here are my build.gradle files:

root/

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/src/

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            returnDefaultValues = true
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }

}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 2
}

ext {
    test_runner_version = '1.0.1'
    espresso_core_version = '2.2.2'
    kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    anko_version = '0.10.1'
    rxjava_version = '2.1.3'
    rxbinding_version = '2.0.0'
    dagger_version = '2.12'
    javax_annotation_version = '10.0-b28'
    jsr250_api_version = '1.0'
    MPAndroidChart_version = 'v3.0.2'
    greendao_version = '3.2.2'
    transitionseverywhere_version = '1.7.5'
    materialprogressbar_version = '1.4.1'
    play_services_fitness_version = '11.4.2'
    kotlinx_coroutines_version = '0.16'
    android_support_version = '26.1.0'
    constraint_layout_version = '1.0.2'
    funktionale_version = '1.1'
    joda_time_version = '2.9.9'
    retrofit2_version = '2.3.0'
    okhttp3_version = '3.6.0'
    butterknife_version = '8.8.1'
    multidex_version = '1.0.2'
    junit_version = '4.12'
    mockito_core_version = '2.8.47'
    mockito_kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    mockwebserver_version = '3.8.0'
    assertj_version = '3.8.0'
    assertj_android_version = '1.2.0'
    robolectric_version = '3.4.2'
    jackson_version = '2.9.1'
    powermock_version = '1.7.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$android_support_version"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:$test_runner_version"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_core_version"

    // kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$rootProject.ext.kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$rootProject.ext.kotlin_version"

    // ANKO
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25-coroutines:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"

    // RXJAVA
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjava_version"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:$rxbinding_version"

    // dagger
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    compileOnly "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:$javax_annotation_version"
    compileOnly "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:$jsr250_api_version"

    // MPAndroidChart
    implementation "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:$MPAndroidChart_version"

    // greenDAO
    implementation "org.greenrobot:greendao:$greendao_version"

    // transitions in older APIs
    implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:$transitionseverywhere_version"

    // material progress bar
    implementation "me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:$materialprogressbar_version"

    // fitness API
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:$play_services_fitness_version"

    // kotlinx
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"

    // appcompat
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$android_support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$android_support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$android_support_version"

    // constraint layout
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraint_layout_version"

    // funktionale
    implementation "org.funktionale:funktionale-all:$funktionale_version"

    // JODA time
    implementation "joda-time:joda-time:$joda_time_version"

    // Retrofit 2
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit2_version"

    // JSONschema
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jackson_version"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:$jackson_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.3.0'

    // Okhttp 3
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3_version"

    // butterknife
    testImplementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife_version"
    kaptTest "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife_version"

    // multidex
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:$multidex_version"

    // test
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$rootProject.ext.kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito_core_version"
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:$mockito_kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$mockwebserver_version"
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:$assertj_version"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectric_version"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.4-rc2"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:$powermock_version"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$powermock_version"

    testImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$android_support_version"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:$assertj_android_version"
}
```

These are the warnings I get when rebuilding the project

```
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [anko-sdk25-coroutines-0.10.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [anko-appcompat-v7-coroutines-0.10.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [rxjava-2.1.3.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [dagger-2.12.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [MPAndroidChart-v3.0.2.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [greendao-3.2.2.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [kotlinx-coroutines-android-0.16.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [kotlinx-coroutines-core-0.16.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [funktionale-all-1.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [joda-time-2.9.9.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [converter-gson-2.3.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [converter-scalars-2.3.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [converter-jackson-2.3.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [retrofit-2.3.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/LICENSE])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/LICENSE])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/NOTICE])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/LICENSE])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/NOTICE])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.properties] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.properties])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.xml] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.xml])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [logging-interceptor-3.6.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [okhttp-3.8.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [anko-appcompat-v7-commons-0.10.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [anko-support-v4-commons-0.10.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [anko-commons-0.10.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [kotlin-stdlib-1.1.51.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [reactive-streams-1.0.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [support-annotations-26.1.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-3.0.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [greendao-api-3.2.2.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [constraint-layout-solver-1.0.2.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.7.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:META-INF/LICENSE])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [common-1.0.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [common-1.0.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [okio-1.13.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.xml] (Duplicate zip entry [okio-1.13.0.jar:META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.xml])
    Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties] (Duplicate zip entry [okio-1.13.0.jar:META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties])
```

I know that these are just warnings and probably do no harm to the app, but
how can I tell gradle to exclude these files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003546/transformclasseswithmultidexlistfordebug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after updating to latest Android Studio version (3.0 RC1).

Answer (score 1):

Add following in your `build.gradle`

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
}
```

Comment: I have tried it earlier and it doesn't seem to do the job, the warnings still occur during rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not your answer, but it maybe can help someone else:

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 my application was having this exactly error building with:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
```

After some wasted hours I found the solution:

```
compile ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'){
   exclude module: 'support-compat'
}
```

Issue link: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/867